# Can We Assign Multiple Attribute Set To One Product?

Tags: magento-1.9

It is possible to assign more than one attribute set for the product one for the color swatches and one for the google map on the main product details page?

I want to do this one on magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

In default Magento it is not possible without doing a customization.

You can create a common attribute set which will have attributes of both "color swatches" and "google map" attribute sets.

Comment: my question is how we can do this?